# Sqlite bulk insert with fresh transaction of a batch

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core

I need to populate a Sqlite table with precalcutated values. Only one table with currently ~20 rows.

After fiddling around a day or two I managed to got the approach 1 working with bulk inserts which works great for "smaller amounts of entries" (5_000_000 records) and it's quite fast. Unfortunately approach 1 hangs somewhere at 139_000_000 records and the iterator will deliver ~ 200_000_000 records by now. The console application does not stop nor throw an exception I could share here.

And I am wondering where the data goes because the memory isn't increasing significantly nor is the database file written (this happens on the commit at the end).

My approach 1:

```
public static void SqliteBulkInsert()
{
    CustomIterator citer = new CostumIterator();

    using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=Iterations.db"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO iterations (V1, V2) VALUES ($V1, $V2)";

            var p1 = command.CreateParameter();
            p1.ParameterName = "$V1";
            command.Parameters.Add(p1);

            var p2 = command.CreateParameter();
            p2.ParameterName = "$V2";
            command.Parameters.Add(p2);

            long i = 0;

            while (citer.Next(out byte v1, out byte v2))
            {
                p1.Value = v1;
                p2.Value = v2;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (i % 10_000 == 0) Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

In a second approach I tried to create a new transaction every batch of 1_000_000. But no matter how I try I received different exceptions like "the transaction of the command does not belong to the current connection" and so on.

When I just add a commit to the batch as in

```
if (i % 10_000 == 0) 
{ 
  transaction.Commit(); 
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I receive:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The transaction object is not associated with the same connection object as this command.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at DevTryOuts.Program.PopulateSqliteCombinationsBulkInsert2() in A:\DevTryOuts\Program.cs:line 568
   at DevTryOuts.Program.Main(String[] args) in A:\DevTryOuts\Program.cs:line 115
```

Any hint how I could correctly implement a new transaction for each batch?

---

There has been some misassumptions:

1. The iterator does not generate 200 million records: it only generates close below 140 million
2. Therefor it reaches the transaction commit (which is the reason the last log entry show 139 million index
3. It "hangs" (including full PC freeze) while writing the records to disk
4. It froze because of unsufficient disk space (~50 GB database) and worked when picking another disk with more free disk space.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have bulk operations. It's an embedded database, there's no separate server and no need for bulk insert operations. The only thing you can eliminate is individual log recors - that's what the explicit transaction is for.  What are the *actual* exceptions you get? If something works for 10 rows, it works for 10M rows.

Comment: Apart from that, if the data comes as a CSV you could open it directly through SQLite as if it was an SQLite database, or access it as [a virtual table](https://sqlite.org/csv.html) and copy the data into your own database. You could use the `sqlite3`  and use eg `.import c:/sqlite/city.csv cities` to import the data into a new table.

Comment: The data does not come from a CSV. It is calculated using the iterator.

If something works for 10 rows it works for 10M rows. Well, maybe. I am currently facing the proof it does not necessarily work with 200M rows.

My expectations are just populating the table. I started with EF Core but that was too slow and took too long. So I worked on approach 1 to improve the speed. I started with that doc snippet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/bulk-insert

Comment: Post the full exception. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` on the exception popup while debugging

Comment: updated the question. Currently trying to create the transaction new for each batch but struggling with the iterator right now.

Comment: `When I just add a commit to the batch as in` that's the problem. This *ends* the transaction. It's only meant to be used at the very end. If you try to use the same transaction again you'll get an error. If you wanted to commit in batches, you should start a new transaction for each batch

Comment: in any case, you didn't post either the original or the current exception. The full exception text contains any inner exceptions and the stack trace with the calls that led to the error. It's quite possible that the exception already tells you the transaction no longer exists

Comment: I now included everything the exception gives me when "copy details". As mentioned approach 1 does not throw any exceptions. It just hangs. With some research the SSD has 100% write activity though disk space does not get reduced and the code did not reach the end of the iterator.

Comment: And yes, that's the problem. And the reason for my question at the end of the OP. :-)

Comment: "Any hint how I could correctly implement a new transaction for each batch?" yes... instantiate a new transaction object for each one...